# Next.js i18n dynamic links with /lang/slug/[id] get error 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When i trying go to /en/vacancies/13 page - getting 404 error
My project looks like - pages/vacancies/[id] file.
If i not use i18n just go to /vacancies/1 - if it is default lang i dont get error

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths<{ id: string }> = async () => {
    let paths;
    await axios.get(`https://career.tele2.kz/cms/vacancies`).then(response => {
        const prePaths = response.data.map((vacancy:any) => {
            const arr = [{ id: vacancy.id.toString(), locale: vacancy.locale }, ...vacancy.localizations];
            arr.map( (it) => {
                return {params: it}
            });
            return arr;
        });
        const merged = [].concat.apply([], prePaths);
        paths = merged.map( (item:any) => {
            return {params: {id: item.id.toString(), locale: item.locale}}
        })
    });
    return { paths, fallback: false }
};
```

this is my getStaticPaths.
My links looks like

```
<Link href={asPath} locale="kz"> // or any different locale
```

How can i solve this 404 error? i don't have directories in pages like en or kz

Comment: Please provide more info on i18 implementation

Comment: The `locale` needs to be outside the `params` object, i.e. `{ params: { id: item.id.toString() }, locale: item.locale }`. Check [i18n Dynamic Routes and `getStaticProps` Pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#dynamic-routes-and-getstaticprops-pages) for more details.